# How to keep AWS APPSync APIs in sync from Dev to Staging to Production?

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, amazon-dynamodb, continuous-delivery, aws-appsync

Let's say you have an *AWS AppSync API* named `API-DEV`. 
It hosts the GraphQL Schema, the Resolvers, the Data sources, DynamoDB tables (ex:`Dev_Articles`), DynamoDB tables configuration, and DynamoDB data. The API is consumed by approx. 50 instances of the same React app.

How would you automate the migration of newest features from `API-DEV` to `API-STAGING`? Note that I want to update everything except data.

Ways to go I'm thinking about:

1. Keep a list of things to update, move the staging apps to maintenance mode, and manually apply the changes to staging env. Seems like a lot of work to do at every "release" and error-prone.
2. Use some kind of YAML template in conjunction with `aws-cli` to store the changes in a GIT repo and automatically deploy on push. Seems like a great way to do this but couldn't find a step-by-step guide, plus, all our config is already in AWS so my guess is that we would have to recreate all using the template.
3. Use some kind of tool that would automate compare and update from two given API and DynamoDB. Not found this yet.
4. Build my own Nodejs app that would leverage `aws-cli` to compare and update. Then have this hosted on *Lamda* and triggered by pushes on the `staging` or `master` branches of the React app repo (Code Commit > Code Build > Code Deploy). That's where I'm heading for now, but there may be an existing solution out there.

Have any other idea? Let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [CloudFormation to model your API](https://read.acloud.guru/deploy-an-aws-appsync-graphql-api-with-amazon-cloudformation-9a783fdd8491). You can then maintain your API configuration, resolvers, and data sources (without data) as code and run that template in the various stages.

To simplify creation of the CloudFormation, you can use the [AWS Amplify CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/announcing-the-aws-amplify-cli-toolchain/) to define the GraphQL schema, which will autogenerate the resolvers for you.

Comment: Super helpful answer, let me dig in before I mark an answer ;-) Thanks Rohan

Comment: I did have my cfts, is there any way to create CI/CD using CFTs?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this: https://github.com/sid88in/serverless-appsync-plugin

Serverless-appsync-plugin makes your life easier. It should have an easier configuration than setting up your own Cloudformation.

Comment: Thanks, Can! I have been using CloudFormation, and despite some limitations on some edges, it works great and is reliable.

Comment: So, today, we have a one CloudFormation template for each environnement, which I keep in sync by using a diff tool, and homemade NodeJS CLI Tools that allows me to deploy data ttransformations.